# Split Text on New Line using Excel & VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to split the text one by one automatically? However, I tried split the text on the active cell only. It cannot do it automatically.

```
PID10 Lemon Tea 

PID11 Mango Tea

PID12 Apple Tea
```

I am using the following for split text

```
Sub NameTest()
    Dim txt As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim FullName As Variant

    Range("txt") = ActiveCell.Value
    FullName = Split(txt, "PID")

    For i = 0 To UBound(FullName)
        Cells(i, i + 1).Value = FullName(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you actually assign a value to `txt`? Also - there is no `0` row in Excel, so `Cells(i, i+1)` will fail on the first iteration of `i`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can achieve what you're trying to do with `TextToColumns`

```
Dim rng As Range

' Sheet with your source values
With ActiveSheet
    ' Range of all values
    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(5, 1))
End With

' Split on spaces in place
rng.TextToColumns
```